# logic for CRUD operation

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am using angular for the CRUD operation .

**Logic:-**

1. I want to use table list and and  edit, create, view methods want to do in a single form.
2. For the table I used the following code for buttons.

**TABLE COMPONENT HTML**

```
    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-plus"class="ui-button-success" label="New" [routerLink]="['/master/productcategory']"> 
    </button>
    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-pencil" iconPos="left" class="ui-button-success" [routerLink]="['/master/productcategory/edit',productcategory.id]">
    </button>
    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-eye" iconPos="left" class="ui-button-success" [routerLink]="['/master/productcategory/view',productcategory.id]"> 
    </button>
```

Following is my table.

[image]

3. When we click on edit, we need to show the **SAVE & CANCEL button**

[image]

4. When we click on the new, we need to show the **CREATE & CANCEL button**

[image]

5. And for view, only **CANCEL button**  to be visible

**Problem:-**

I used the logic that, when the id pass from the table, then it save into the  variable **productCategoryIdToUpdate**.

Then using if else condition I wrote that,

IF`(productCategoryIdToUpdate === null`) then do the CREATE function. ELSE do the update function.

Now I need to pass the id for both edit and view. Because of logic which I wrote, same edit form shows in VIEW form too.

How can I write the logic for edit and view. Can anybody help me??

** FORM HTML:-**

```
    <div class="ui-grid-col-1">
        <button type="submit" pButton label="Create" 
          [disabled]="!productCategoryForm.valid" 
          *ngIf="!productCategoryIdToUpdate">
        </button>
        <button type="submit" pButton label="Save" 
          [disabled]="!productCategoryForm.valid" 
          *ngIf="productCategoryIdToUpdate">
        </button>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-grid-col-1">
        <button type="button" class="ui-button-secondary" pButton 
            label="Cancel" (click)="backToCreateProductCategories()"> 
        </button>
      </div>
```

**FORM COMPONENT.TS**

```
onProductCategoryFormSubmit() {
    if (this.productCategoryForm.invalid) {
        return; 
    }
   let productCategory = this.productCategoryForm.value;
   if (this.productCategoryIdToUpdate === null) {
     //Create product
       this.service.createProductCategory(productCategory).subscribe(
        successCode => {
         this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Product Created' });
      this.backToCreateProductCategories() ;
      }
     );
  } else {
  //Handle update product
     productCategory.id = this.productCategoryIdToUpdate;
     this.service.updateProductCategory(productCategory).subscribe(
       successCode => {
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Product Editted' });
     }
   );
  }
 }
```

To go back to the table (cancel button)

```
    backToCreateProductCategories() {
       this.productCategoryIdToUpdate = null;
       this.router.navigate(['/master/productcategories']);
    }
```

Comment: you can try to use flags like "isEditing" "isAdding" and bind the `[enabled]="isAdding"` or `[enabled]="isEditing"` on the component.. update those on `(click)` for the actions and cancel.. should be fine and simple

Comment: Can u help me?? how to use the flags??

Comment: Can you elaborate it or just provide short code

Comment: I added a stackblitz sample of the code on the response, if you interact with the buttons `add`, `edit` and `cancel` you should see the outcome of the buttons becomming disabled/enabled.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using flags, properties that you can use to change the behavior based on user interaction.

Each time the user clicks a button, you know what the user intent is, so you can enable/disable elements or display / hide based on that.

In this scenario, you can use isAdding and isEditing to enable and disable buttons as you see fit.

in your component:

```
isEditing = false;
isAdding = false;

  onAdd() {
    this.isAdding = true;

    // your logic goes here
  }

  onEdit() {
    this.isEditing = true;

    // your logic goes here
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.isAdding = false;
    this.isEditing = false;
  }
```

on your view:

```
<button [disabled]="isEditing" (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
<button [disabled]="isAdding" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
<button (click)="onCancel" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Is that clear? How to apply to your scenario?

I added a simple [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmrbga)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case,we cant write the click function in button. The table is in a component and the form is in the another component. EDIT,CREATE and  NEW button is in table and we pass the id through routing into form. Based on that I wrote the function in form component.

Comment: well, then your question is not about angular, but about the component you're using and you posted html for the buttons.. so I don't understand exactly.. the `onAdd` is your submit.. worst case scenario, create a working example on stackblitz.. so people can reproduce it

Comment: No, I need the logic. What I used was. If the id pass , do the update function else do the create function. We don't want to pass for create and  need to pass the id for both edit and view. Now when I click on the view, id pass to the component and showing the edit form. In the case of edit and view, I don't know how to write.